# Console not showing printed output

Tags: c#, wpf, console, .net-4.5

I use a console with my WPF app to print out debug info. The console is opened like this:

```
static class DebugConsole //Console window handling class
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private static extern bool FreeConsole();

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetConsoleOutputCP();

    public static bool HasConsole
    {
        get { return GetConsoleWindow() != IntPtr.Zero; }
    }

    static public void Open() //Open console window
    {
        AllocConsole();

        Console.WriteLine("test");

    }
}
```

.. meanwhile in another part of the editor..

```
    public MainWindow() //This gets executed when the application starts
    {
        DebugConsole.Open();

        InitializeComponent();                               
    }
```

When I launch the application with the code above, everything works as expected. A console window is opened and a word "test" is printed out in the console.

However, if I change the MainWindow() code to this:

```
    public MainWindow() //This gets executed when the application starts
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test1");

        DebugConsole.Open();

        InitializeComponent();                               
    }
```

and run the application...

Expected output: The console opens and it will contain two lines of text

```
test1
test
```

Actual output: The console opens and it contains no text at all. In fact, I can use Console.WriteLine all I want after that in the code and the console remains empty. It only works, if no Console.WriteLine is used, before the console is opened.

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: I was able to create a small console app with your code in it and I am getting the output you expect (test1 on first line, test on second line).  Have you tried setting a breakpoint on your MainWindow() method to make sure it is getting executed as you expect?  I'd try stepping through that to see the output line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

Print after you initialize the console. Switch  `Console.WriteLine("test1")` and `DebugConsole.Open()`

**EDIT:**
When you use `Console.Writeline` without initializing a console I think that it returns a `NullStream()` (just like when you redirect data to null on Unix) but when you call `open` your write methods use the real standard output.
So the stream used by default is NullStream() else it is the standard output.
check [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs)